# Django many to many annotations and filters with Count

Tags: django, django-queryset

So I have two models, `Person` and `Film` where they're in a many to many relationship. My goal is to grab a film, and output the persons that have also appeared in at least 10 films.

For example I can get the count individually by:

```
>>> Person.objects.get(short__istartswith = "Matt Damon").film_set.count()
71
```

However, if I try to filter all the actors of a particular film out:

```
>>> Film.objects.get(name__istartswith="Saving Private Ryan").actors.all().annotate(film_count=Count('film')).filter(film_count__gte=10)
[]
```

it returns an empty set since if I manually look at everyone's `film_count` it's 1, even though an actor such as Matt Damon (as seen above) has been in 71 films in my db.

As you can see with this query, the annotation doesn't work:

```
>>> Film.objects.get(name__istartswith="Saving Private Ryan").actors.all().annotate(film_count=Count('film'))[0].film_count
1
>>> Film.objects.get(name__istartswith="Saving Private Ryan").actors.all().annotate(film_count=Count('film'))[0].film_set.count()
7
```

and I can't seem to figure out a way to filter it by the `film_set.count()`

Answer (score 0):

So I figured one way, which I'm not sure is the most efficient query, is to annotate all the persons first, then try to filter it based on film and film count:

```
Person.objects.annotate(film_count=Count('film')).filter(film__name__istartswith="Saving Private Ryan").filter(film_count__gte=10)
```